# Is sqrt still slow in Delphi 2009?

Tags: performance, delphi, optimization, delphi-2009

Is sqrt still slow in Delphi 2009?

Are the old tricks (lookup table, approx functions) still useful?

Comment: i am guessing Delphi? language please

Comment: "...still...": Compared to which version of Delphi?

Comment: Actually I was talking about c.
The answers are however interesting, so I'll post a separate C version

Comment: @Mykelyk: Do you think maybe asking the question and including the language you are talking about might help? Perhaps at least editing the answer after people have asked for the language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are dealing with a small set of really large numbers then a lookup table will most always be faster.  While if you are dealing with a large set of small numbers then even a slow routine may be faster then maintaining a large table.

I looked in System.pas (where **SQRT** is located) and while there are a number of blocks marked as licensed from the *Fastcode project*, **SQRT** is not.  In fact, it just makes an assembly call to **FSQRT**, so it most likely hasn't changed.  So if it was comparatively slow at one point then it most likely still is as slow (although your CPU may be a lot faster and optimized for that now . . . .)

My recommendation is to look at your usage and test.

Comment: Right.  I don't believe there are any optimizations over using FSQRT or a look-up table.

Comment: My usage is a physic simulation game

Comment: You are really going to need to optimize it for your usage.  If you see that you are calculating the same large square roots repeatedly then you might consider caching them, but that will probably only be faster if you are dealing with large numbers.  Small numbers will probably be faster to just calculate each time.  Of course you will need to test and see.

Answer (score 3):

Many moons ago I had an app that computed distance to sort vectors. I realized sorting by the un-sqrt-ed values was the same so I skipped it altogether. Sorted by distance^2 and saved some time.

Comment: Yes, I've done this sort of thing more than once.  Very often you can work with distance^2 instead of distance.

Comment: exactly. comparing dot products are just as good as comparing magnitudes. (sadly, it doesn't work with ratios.)

Answer (score 1):

My answer to questions of efficiency is to just apply the simplest method first, then optimize later.  Making an operation faster when there's no need for it to be all that fast in the first place seems silly.

I digress, however, since my answer is about efficiency, not the historical aspects of your question.

Comment: So, basically, this isn't an answer at all.

Comment: There are two parts to his question, one is about efficiency and the other is about the historical nature of the function.  He obviously isn't looking to optimize an existing implementation, so why not try it first then see if the performance is tolerable.